# populating date_select field with out db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have model that isn't reliant on a database. It fetches data using a SOAP API.  When editing and object, my date selector automatically resets to the current day, instead of using the value returned via the API. How do I get my date_select form helper to use the date supplied via said API?

form:

```
    <%= date_select :start_time, :created, {:add_month_numbers => true } %>
```

edit action:

```
.....
@keyword = Keyword.new

@keyword.id = @result[0][:value]

@keyword.name = @result[1][:value]

@keyword.keyword = @result[2][:value]

@keyword.message1 = @result[3][:value]

@keyword.message2 = @result[4][:value]

@keyword.start_time = @result[5][:value]
```

the value of @result[5][:value] looks like "yyyy-mm-dd" and is returned as a string.
How can I get my date_select to properly reflect this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the :default option to set the default date:

```
<%= date_select :start_time, :created, :add_month_numbers => true, :default => Time.parse(@keyword.start_time) %>
```

[API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select)